# Put breakline in XSLT output

Tags: xml, xslt

XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProcessData>
    <SOAPAction>urn:echo</SOAPAction>
    <Content_Type>text/xml;charset=UTF-8</Content_Type>
    <uname>sarah_brcm</uname>
    <pwd>BRCM_UVLwNhjrA5fbgqkUNdxQXMfcCDJ</pwd>
</ProcessData>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="ProcessData/SOAPAction/text()"/>
    <br/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="ProcessData/Content_Type/text()"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the Output does not contain break line between first two lines.

Comment: I've checked your code on http://xslttest.appspot.com/ and it works. How do you run the transformation? In browser? libxslt? ...saxon? Also you probably need "html" output method, not "xml"

Comment: @kgb you are right. It should be output method="html". thanks a lot. If you post your answer separately than I can mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked your code on xslttest.appspot.com and it works. How do you run the transformation? In browser? libxslt? ...saxon? Also you probably need "html" output method, not "xml"

Answer (score 1):

`<br/>` is for output HTML. I suggest you to use `&#13;` if you want to insert a line feed within data node.

**html:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="ProcessData/SOAPAction/text()"/>
    <br/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="ProcessData/Content_Type/text()"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="ProcessData/SOAPAction/text()"/>
       <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
       <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:copy-of select="ProcessData/Content_Type/text()"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```